# C++ Sudden iostream issues

Tags: c++

I was just about to send off my completed code for my project only to be met with a sudden barrage of errors of ambiguous "cout"s and "cin"s as well as a few if and while blocks expecting declarations. At first I expected that I was missing iostream or a namespace, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. Any clue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

#include "ARRAY.H"

using namespace std;

void addToArray(Array<int> &intArray);
void linearSearch();
void binarySearch(Array<int> &intarray, int beg, int end);
void printArray();
void sortArray();
void Remove(int p_index);
void clear();
void testFunctions();
void pop();

    Array<int> intarray(10);
    int num_elements = 10;


int main()
{
    intarray[0] = 42;
    intarray[1] = 6;
    intarray[2] = 2;
    intarray[3] = 51;
    intarray[4] = 16;
    intarray[5] = 13;
    intarray[6] = 44;
    intarray[7] = 19;
    intarray[8] = 26;
    intarray[9] = 88;

    intarray.WriteFile("unorderedArray.txt");

    testFunctions();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         testFunctions
//  Description:  General testing of all the functions
//  Arguments:    None.
// -------------------------------------------------------

void testFunctions()
{
    intarray.ReadFile("unorderedArray.txt");

    printArray();

    sortArray();

    Remove(4);

    addToArray(intarray);

    linearSearch();

    binarySearch(intarray, 0, intarray.Size());


    //clear();

    pop();


    printArray();


    intarray.WriteFile("orderedArray.txt");

    cout<<"\nThis concludes our tests. Full marks please!"<<endl;

    Sleep(10000);


}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         addToArray
//  Description:  Allows users to insert a new element into the array
//                at an index of their choosing
//  Arguments:    The Array
// -------------------------------------------------------

void addToArray(Array<int> &intarray)
{
    int newValue; //the value to be added to the array
    int newIndex; //the index location of the new array
    int grow_size; //the amount the array will grow by if it is full

    if(num_elements == intarray.Size() ) //If array is full but user wants to add to it, they will be prompted to increase it's size before being allowed to add an elememt
        {
            cout<<"\nArray is full!!!!! How much do you want to grow it?"<<endl;
            cin>> grow_size;
            intarray.Resize(intarray.Size() + grow_size); //creates a new larger array and copies everything over
            cout<<"Array resized"<<endl;
        }

    cout<<"What do you want to add to the array?"<<endl;
    cin >> newValue;
    cout<<"At what point should this value be added?"<<endl;
    cin >> newIndex;

    intarray.Insert(newValue, newIndex);
    num_elements++; 

    sortArray(); //sorts the values from smallest to largest
    printArray();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         linearSearch
//  Description:  Searches through the Array from start to finish for the
//                inputted value.
//  Arguments:    None.
// -------------------------------------------------------

void linearSearch()
{
    int search; //the search key
    int result = 0; 

    cout<<"\nEnter Element you want to Search=";
    cin>>search;

    for(int i=1;i<=intarray.Size();i++)  //goes through each element of the array until it finds the value in the key.                    
        if(intarray[i]==search)
            {
            cout<<"\nData is Found at Location : "<<i;
            result=1;
            break;
            }
        }

        if(result==0)
            {
            cout<<"Data is Not Found";
            }

        cout<<"\n"<<endl;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         binarySearch
//  Description:  Uses a B-Tree format to search for inputted 
//                values of a sorted array
//  Arguments:    The Array, int beg: the start of the Array, int end: The end of the Array
// -------------------------------------------------------

void binarySearch(Array<int> &intarray, int beg, int end)
{
        int key; //the value to be searched for
        cout<<"\nEnter Item you want to Search= ";
        cin>>key;
        int mid; // the middle of the array

        //beg=1;
        //end=intarray.Size();

        mid=(beg+end)/2; //the middle point of the array is found by adding the beginning and end values and dividing them by two.                      

        while(beg<=end && intarray[mid]!=key) //While the mid value does not equal the key, if it is smaller it adds 1 to the beginning but if it is            
            //larger it subtracts 1 from the end and then the value of the middle point is found again. This continues until either the mid value equals the key value  
        {
        if(intarray[mid]<key)
        beg=mid+1;
        else
        end=mid-1;

        mid=(beg+end)/2;
        }

        if(intarray[mid]==key)
        {
        cout<<"\nData is Found at Location : "<<mid;
        }
        else
        {
        cout<<"Data is Not Found";
        }
} 

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         printArray
//  Description:  prints the array
//  Arguments:    None.
// -------------------------------------------------------

void printArray()
{
    int i = intarray[0];


    cout<<"\n The contents of the array are : "<<endl;

       cout<<"\n     Elements :"<<"\t\t     Value:"<<endl;

       for (i=0;i<intarray.Size();i++) //goes through each element of the array and prints them nice and neat
         cout<<" \tarray ["<<i<<"]"<<"\t\t  "<<intarray[i]<<endl;

}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         sortArray
//  Description:  sorts the Array from smallest value to largest
//  Arguments:    None.
// -------------------------------------------------------

void sortArray()
{
    cout<<"\nSorting array..."<<endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < intarray.Size(); i++)
    {
        // nSmallestIndex is the index of the smallest element found so far
        int nSmallestIndex = i;

        // Searches through every element starting at nStartIndex+1
        for (int nCurrentIndex = i + 1; nCurrentIndex < intarray.Size(); nCurrentIndex++)
        {
            // If the current element is smaller than the previously found smallest it becomes the new smallest index
            if (intarray[nCurrentIndex] < intarray[nSmallestIndex])
                nSmallestIndex = nCurrentIndex;
        }

        // Swap the start element with the smallest element
        swap(intarray[i], intarray[nSmallestIndex]);


    }

        printArray();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         Remove
//  Description:  Removes an element from the array and
//                resizes it.
//  Arguments:    int p_index: The index of the element to be deleted
// -------------------------------------------------------

void Remove(int p_index)
{
int index;

    cout<<"\nRemoving index "<<p_index<<" from array"<<endl;

          // move everything after the deleted element down by one cell.
          for(index = p_index + 1; index < intarray.Size(); index++)
          {
              intarray.m_array[index - 1] = intarray.m_array[index];
          }

          //Resizes the array by reducing it by one so that the last value is not duplicated
          intarray.Resize(intarray.Size() -1);
          num_elements--;

          printArray();
 }

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         clear
//  Description:  "clears" the array by changing all the values to 0
//  Arguments:    None.
// -------------------------------------------------------

void clear()
{
    //goes through each element of the array and changes all the values to 0.
    for(int i=0; i < intarray.Size(); i++)
        {
        intarray[i]=0;
        }
    printArray();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:         pop
//  Description:  Pops off the last element of the array
//  Arguments:    None.
// -------------------------------------------------------

void pop()
{
    //Reduces the size of the array by one, chopping off the last element.
    cout<<"\nPopping off the last element of the Array"<<endl;
          intarray.Resize(intarray.Size() -1);
          num_elements++;
}
```

errors:

> 1>c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(198): error C2872: 'cout' : ambiguous symbol 1> could be 'c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(144) : int cout' 1> or 'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iostream(26) : std::ostream std::cout' 1>c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(198): error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char [35]' 1>c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(198): error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter lis

Comment: Care to share the error messages you got?

Comment: You could do with including windows.h after the standard headers. Some of the #defines in there can mess about with other headers.

Comment: 1>c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(198): error C2872: 'cout' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(144) : int cout'
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iostream(26) : std::ostream std::cout'
1>c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(198): error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char [35]'
1>c:\users\liam\desktop\orderedarray\orderedarray\main.cpp(198): error C2563: mismatch in formal parameter list

Comment: Whoops, meant to format that. But yeah, it's pretty much an endless ream of errors like that

Comment: Please edit your question to include those error messages, and indicate which are lines 198, 144, etc.

Comment: Maybe there are things you can remove without changing the error you get?

Comment: Hang on, I managed to fix it myself. I scanned through the error messages and found that I was missing a bracket in one of the functions. The code now seems to run fine, so I guess the problem has been solved! Thanks to everyone for their suggestions, crisis averted!

Comment: @Liam you really should pick and indent style and follow it, preferably using an editor that does the work for you. This just hurts my eyes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hang on, I managed to fix it myself. I scanned through the error messages and found that I was missing a bracket in one of the functions. The code now seems to run fine, so I guess the moral for all newbie coders is if your entire program is suddenly full of errors, check to see if all the brackets are paired properly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you specify which bracket?

Comment: @Antonio the for-loop in `linearSearch` looks a bit suspicious.